# Correct way to plot with wolframscript

Tags: plotting, scripting

I am trying to run a .m file with wolfram script. I use the command

```
wolframscript -file name.m
```

It works until the program arrives to a `Plot`. I know that with wolfrascipt I cannot produce a graphic on screen as with the front-end, so I tried to suppress the output with a `;`, as follows:

```
plot=Plot[Sin[x],{x,-Pi,Pi}];
```

and later to `Export` `plot`, but it still does not run.

How do I produce and save a plot with wolframscript?

Comment: I forgot: I use Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not run"? Can you show the screenshot from the command line? Writing ``plot=Plot[Sin[x],{x,-Pi,Pi}]; Export["test.png", plot];`` should produce a valid output image ...